# How to describe a value that can be serialized correctly?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that only works correctly if the object passed can be serialized, in other words if it contains no Symbols and functions:

```
 createHash("test"); // Will work
 createHash({ test: "test", method() { } }); // Will not work, throw type error

 function createHash<T>(data: Serializable<T>): Hash<T> {
   const salt = createSalt();
   return { salt, hash: CryptoJS.PBKDF2(JSON.stringify(data), salt).toString(), };
 }
```

I was able to write the following type definition:

```
type Serializable<T> = 
  T extends (Function | symbol) ? never : 
  T extends (string | number | boolean) ? T : 
  { [K in keyof T]: Serializable<T[K]> };
```

But this does not work in all cases, namely when passing those Serializables between two functions I get:

```
Argument of type 'Serializable<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
'Serializable<T>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.
```

... and the error it provides is also not quite useful:

```
createHash({ test: "test", method() { } }); // Type "() => void is not assignable to type never"
```

So my question is: How can I type Serializable in a way that it generates useful error messages and works without manually specifying T?

Comment: there's on-(and off-)going discussion about this on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1897), started in 2015